Merge a table row into several rows and match their column names
This is a simplified version of my problem:
I have three articles: 1111 = oranges, 1112 = apples and 1113 =lemons.
The prices of these are in a table like this:



Cust_Nr
Article
Price




23
1111
4


23
1112
4


23
1113
4


32
1111
5


32
1113
5



Note there is no row for Customer 32 and Article 1112. This is normal and expected, that I should not have prices for certain combinations of customer/article. Storing 0 or NULL values here as placeholders is not desirable for this application. The actual data would have far too many permutations to make this reasonable.
Now I get the following table from another system. I need to insert this data in the table above:



Cust_Nr
Oranges
Apples
Lemons




43
0
4
0


52
5
0
5


32
4
0
5



Now I would like to merge this data in the table above matching the article numbers to oranges, apples and lemons. This should omit articles when the price is zero, and update the price for existing customer/article records when there is a match.
The result should be:



Customer
Article
Price




23
1111
4


23
1112
4


23
1113
4


32
1111
4


32
1113
5


43
1112
4


52
1111
5


52
1113
5



I will have to do this again and again. Prices may have changed, and a price for articles may have to be inserted where there has been no line before because of price zero. However, a MERGE command cannot write several rows from one input line. The customer numbers do not need to be in sequential order, and I do not want to add "0" records.
How can I solve this?
As suggested I used unpivot now:
drop table if exists #fruits
drop table if exists #mytest

CREATE TABLE #fruits
(
  Cust_NR INT,
  Oranges int,
  Apples int,
  Lemons int,
);

INSERT #fruits
  (Cust_Nr, Oranges, Apples, Lemons)
VALUES
  (43,0,4,0),
  (52,5,0,5)
------------------------------------------
SELECT Cust_Nr, Price
into #mytest
FROM
(
  SELECT Cust_Nr, Oranges, Apples, Lemons 
  FROM #fruits
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  Price FOR Dummy IN (Oranges , Apples, Lemons)
) AS up;

select * from #mytest

This results in:



Cust_Nr
Price




43
0


43
4


43
0


52
5


52
0


52
5



This is a big step forward. But how do I add the column for the article numbers?

Where do you store that 1111 = oranges? Or do you just memorize that?

I just know that. I guess I will have to build a table for that. So far I used case statements to match them.

Yes, please put those relationships in a table. That's what tables are for. :-) Otherwise you end up with these complicated (and ever-changing, it sounds like) case expressions all over your codebase.

You can flip your merge table into multiple rows by using UNPIVOT , and it should be mergeable just fine, either using the merge new hotness or just an old hat insert/update

I have edited my question to try the unpivot suggestion.

Added a row to the sample data to demonstrate how (I think) you want that treated. (It shows that the price for oranges for customer 32 should change from 5 to 4), so we have an example of how to modify an existing customer.

I still have one question though: could your input ever tell you to DELETE a record? For example, could you get a row like this: (23, 0, 4, 4), which omits any price for Oranges for customer 23, even though there is one currently in the table. Would that mean to DELETE the existing record? Ignore it? Or something you just know can't happen? You should add this yourself as another sample row and update the results accordingly.

This can happen, but it is so rare that I would leave a record with a zero price in the table.

You can try add unpivot column Dummy to select clause for next step. SELECT Cust_Nr, Price,Dummy into #mytest FROM (   SELECT Cust_Nr, Oranges, Apples, Lemons    FROM #fruits ) AS cp UNPIVOT  (   Price FOR Dummy IN (Oranges , Apples, Lemons) ) AS up; 

Yes, that works! Thank you.

You can subsitute Dummy (FruitName) by article by join with ( values(1111,'oranges'), (1112,'apples'),(1113,'lemons')       )FruitArticle(article,FruitName)

ValNik, can you please provide more lines to show where this join is used?

Posting a complete example of how i'd go about this:
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM
    (
    VALUES  (23, 1111, 4)
    ,   (23, 1112, 4)
    ,   (23, 1113, 4)
    ,   (32, 1111, 5)
    ,   (32, 1113, 5)
) t (Cust_Nr,Article,Price)

SELECT  *
INTO    #incoming 
FROM
(
    VALUES  (43, 0, 4, 0)
    ,   (52, 5, 0, 5)
    ,   (32, 4, 0, 5)
) t (Cust_Nr,Oranges,Apples,Lemons)

SELECT  *
INTO    #mapping 
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1111, 'Oranges')
    ,   (1112, 'Apples')
    ,   (1113, 'Lemons')
    ) x (Article, Product)

;MERGE #data AS target
USING (
    SELECT  Cust_Nr, up.Price, mp.Article
    FROM    #incoming i
        UNPIVOT (
          Price FOR Product IN (Oranges , Apples, Lemons)
        ) up
    INNER JOIN #mapping mp
        ON  mp.Product = up.Product
    ) AS source
    ON  source.Cust_Nr = target.Cust_nr
    AND source.Article = target.Article
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND source.Price > 0 THEN 
    INSERT (Cust_Nr, Article, Price)
    VALUES(Cust_Nr, Article, Price)
WHEN    MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET Price = source.Price
output  $action, inserted.*, deleted.*
;

You need to keep a mapping table between products and IDs, then it's just a case of UNPIVOTing the incoming data and joining on this mapping table.
Finally, i use a standard MERGE, the little wrinkle is that you didn't want to add price = 0, so i have a little check before INSERTing the new values.
I've added a little OUTPUT for demostration purposes, for normal operations, it's not needed.

Thank you for this solution!

I was able to implement this by using CROSS APPLY and CASE statement mapping.
Below is the query for merging.
MERGE INTO #price_table AS Target
USING (
    SELECT
        ft.Cust_Nr,
        CASE v.ArticleName
            WHEN 'Oranges' THEN 1111
            WHEN 'Apples' THEN 1112
            WHEN 'Lemons' THEN 1113
        END AS Article,
        v.Price
    FROM #fruits ft
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('Oranges', ft.Oranges),
        ('Apples', ft.Apples),
        ('Lemons', ft.Lemons)
    ) v(ArticleName, Price)
    WHERE v.Price <> 0
) AS Source
ON (Target.Cust_Nr = Source.Cust_Nr AND Target.Article = Source.Article)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Price = Source.Price
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Cust_Nr, Article, Price)
    VALUES (Source.Cust_Nr, Source.Article, Source.Price);

This query would update the #price_table like below:



Cust_Nr
Article
Price




23
1111
4


23
1112
4


23
1113
4


32
1111
4


32
1113
5


43
1112
4


52
1111
5


52
1113
5



Here is the DBFiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/vrSPNyC2

Thank you. I do not see where "v" is defined. Can you please explain this? It does not appear on DBFiddle too.

v has been defined. It's the alias for the derived table resulting from CROSS APPLY (VALUES ...), with columns ArticleName and Price. It helps to unpivot the wide format data (multiple columns for each fruit) into a long format (multiple rows), which is necessary for the MERGE operation. And DBFiddle link works as well. Scroll down to see the result.

Thank you, I have no doubt that the code works but I try to figure out why. :-) I am not familiar with the CROSS APPLY command, therefore the question.

Ok, no problem! I recommend you to learn more about CROSS APPLY which is a specific feature in SQL Server. In other SQL engines, the similar functionality can be achieved using other methods like INNER JOIN combined with subqueries or derived tables. But, CROSS APPLY directly helps to simplify complex queries and helps to allow more complex transformations and calculations. I believe you'll like it a lot once you get more familiar with CROSS APPLY.

You can merge main table (mytest in example) with new data.
1.First, UNPIVOT new incoming data. Your query do this.
2.Assign article to every row of above. In the example, this is done using using JOIN with a list of values. You can use the permanent table of correspondence of names to articles here. The result of this stage is shown separately below in the answer.
3.The next stage is actually MERGE. Here we see possible options for choice action, that @JoelCoehoorn pointed out.
3.1 A simple case is when such a row is missing in the table - we just add a new row (INSERT).
3.2 When row exists and new value is 0, we DELETE this row. Your possible case is - UPDATE with 0 existing row.
3.3 When row exist and new value is not 0 then UPDATE row with new value.
See example
Data example:



Cust_Nr
Article
Price




23
1111
4


23
1112
4


23
1113
4


32
1111
5


32
1113
5






Cust_NR
Oranges
Apples
Lemons




43
0
4
0


52
5
0
5


32
4
0
5



merge into mytest
using (
  select Cust_Nr, article,Price -- ,nm ,FruitName
  from(
    SELECT Cust_Nr, Price,FruitName
    FROM(
      SELECT Cust_Nr, Oranges, Apples, Lemons 
      FROM #fruits
     ) AS cp
  UNPIVOT 
   (
     Price FOR FruitName IN (Oranges , Apples, Lemons)
   ) AS up
  )t
  left join ( values(1111,'oranges'), (1112,'apples'),(1113,'lemons')
        )FruitArticle(article,FruitName) 
             on FruitArticle.FruitName=t.FruitName
--where price>0
)src on mytest.cust_nr=src.cust_nr and mytest.Article=src.article
  when matched  and src.price>0 then
     update set price=src.price
  when matched  and src.price=0 then
     delete 
  when not matched and price>0 then
    insert(cust_nr,article,price) values(src.cust_nr,src.article,src.price)
;
select * from mytest




Cust_Nr
Article
Price




23
1111
4


23
1112
4


23
1113
4


32
1111
4


32
1113
5


43
1112
4


52
1111
5


52
1113
5



Intermediate output for Unpivot and JOIN wit FruitArticle
select Cust_Nr, Price,t.FruitName   ,FruitArticle.FruitName,FruitArticle.article 
from(
  SELECT Cust_Nr, Price,FruitName
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Cust_Nr, Oranges, Apples, Lemons 
    FROM #fruits
  ) AS cp
  UNPIVOT 
  (
    Price FOR FruitName IN (Oranges , Apples, Lemons)
  ) AS up
 )t
left join ( values(1111,'oranges'), (1112,'apples'),(1113,'lemons')
      )FruitArticle(article,FruitName) 
    on FruitArticle.FruitName=t.FruitName
order by Cust_nr,FruitArticle.article




Cust_Nr
Price
FruitName
FruitName
article




32
4
Oranges
oranges
1111


32
0
Apples
apples
1112


32
5
Lemons
lemons
1113


43
0
Oranges
oranges
1111


43
4
Apples
apples
1112


43
0
Lemons
lemons
1113


52
5
Oranges
oranges
1111


52
0
Apples
apples
1112


52
5
Lemons
lemons
1113



This fragment may be substituted by permanent table in your base.
select * from ( values(1111,'oranges'), (1112,'apples'),(1113,'lemons'))f(Article,FruitName)




Article
FruitName




1111
oranges


1112
apples


1113
lemons



create table MyTest (Cust_Nr int,   Article int,    Price int);
insert into MyTest values
 (23,   1111,   4)
,(23,   1112,   4)
,(23,   1113,   4)
,(32,   1111,   5)
,(32,   1113,   5)
;
CREATE TABLE #fruits ( Cust_NR INT, Oranges int, Apples int, Lemons int,);
 
INSERT #fruits (Cust_Nr, Oranges, Apples, Lemons)VALUES
  (43,0,4,0),
  (52,5,0,5),
  (32,4,0,5)
  ;

fiddle

Thank you very much, ValNik!
